# Oracle stored procedure stuck

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm having a problem with a stored procedure on oracle 11g.

I create this procedure and when I run it on sql developer it gets stuck.
The execution never ends and nothing is printed out.

**Procedure:**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "GET_RECORDS_SP" (CURSOR_ OUT sys_refcursor, PARAM_0 VARCHAR2,PARAM_1 VARCHAR2)
AS
myquery varchar2(255);
  BEGIN  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.enable();
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PARAM_0);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- 1 --');
    CASE
      WHEN PARAM_0 = 'A' THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- 2 --');
        myquery := 'SELECT * FROM table
               WHERE char_field = ''N'' and date_field is not null';
      WHEN PARAM_0 = 'B' THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- 3 --');
        myquery:= 'SELECT * FROM table
              WHERE char_field = ''N'' and 
              date_field is not null and
              char_field2 = '''||PARAM_1||'''';
      WHEN PARAM_0 = 'C' THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- 4 --');
        myquery:= 'SELECT * FROM table 
              WHERE char_field = ''N'' and
              date_field is not null 
              and char_field3 = ''S''';
    END CASE;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(myquery);
  OPEN CURSOR_ FOR myquery;
END;
```

If I comment the line `OPEN CURSOR_ FOR myquery;` it prints `A`, `-- 1 --`, `-- 2 --` and the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE char_field = ''N'' and date_field is not null` (passing `A` in `PARAM_0`).

If I try to run the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE char_field = ''N'' and date_field is not null` alone, it executes and give me the results.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my procedure?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you run your procedure?

Comment: I run it on SQL Developer with the execute button (Ctrl+F10).

Comment: Do you have access to `v$session` view? I would begin from querying this view to know what exactly database do right now.

Comment: Nope. `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Comment: I got this error in test database. In production database, I have access.

Comment: I don't know what I should look for.

Comment: If I pass `B` or `C` in the `PARAM_0` the procedure runs ok. Could the problem be the number of records of the first query? (count = 742562 records)

Comment: Yes, it could. Also, when you are querying `v$session` view, look at columns `status` and `sql_id`. `Status` shows does the session do anything right now, and `sql_id` contains identifier of currently running query, which you can find in `v$sql` view. Also you can use package `dbms_application_info` for debug. Sorry, forgot to answer earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was querying more fields than I needed.

So I change the query from:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE char_field = ''N'' and date_field is not null';
```

To:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM table WHERE char_field = ''N'' and date_field is not null';
```

And now the procedure is not getting stuck any more. It is not so fast but I get the results.